# Combining functions in a GUI to create new functions

Tags: python

I'm currently working on an app that allows users to create custom functions by "grouping" existing functions together. To provide a more user-friendly interface, I want to implement a GUI where users can drag functions from a list, give them a name, and define parameters that they can pass later, similar to how it's done in Scratch language.

For demonstration purposes, I have a simplified code with two functions, Sync and SupC, which I can combine using a FunctionNode. The current code allows me to set up the functions and their arguments programmatically. Let's say I want to create a foo function by combining Sync and SupC functions, like bellow:

```py
def Sync(*args):
    text = ''
    for automato in args:
        text += automato.name + ' + ' 
    return text.rstrip(' + ')

def SupC(text1:Automaton, text2:Automaton):
    result = ''
    for letter in text1.name:
        if letter not in text2.name:
            result += letter
    return result
    
def foo(sync1, sync2):
    return SupC(Sync(sync1), Sync(sync2))
```

However, I'm implementing it with a GUI, the user won't interact with python code. Here's what I got so far:

```py
from inspect import signature

class FunctionNode:
    def __init__(self, func, name=None, args=None):
        if name is None:
            self.name = func.__name__
        else:
            self.name = name
        self.func = func
        self.args = args if args else []
        self.func_arguments = {param: None for param in signature(func).parameters}
        self.user_parameters = dict()

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.name}(func_arguments={self.func_arguments}, user_parameters={self.user_parameters})'

    def pass_argument(self, arg, value):
        if arg not in self.func_arguments:
            raise ValueError(f'Function {self.func.__name__} does not have argument {arg}')
        if callable(value):
            self.func_arguments[arg] = FunctionNode(value)
        elif isinstance(value, str):
            self.func_arguments[arg] = None
            self.user_parameters[arg] = value
        else:
            self.func_arguments[arg] = value

    def set_function_name(self, name):
        self.name = name


class Automaton:
    def __init__(self, name=None):
        self.name = name
        

def Sync(*args):
    text = ''
    for automato in args:
        text += automato.name + ' + ' 
    return text.rstrip(' + ')

def SupC(text1:Automaton, text2:Automaton):
    result = ''
    for letter in text1.name:
        if letter not in text2.name:
            result += letter
    return result

node = FunctionNode(SupC, name='foo')
node.pass_argument('text1', Sync)
node.pass_argument('text2', Sync)
node.func_arguments['text1'].pass_argument('args', Sync)
node.func_arguments['text2'].pass_argument('args', Sync)
node.func_arguments['text1'].func_arguments['args'].pass_argument('args', 'sync1')
node.func_arguments['text2'].func_arguments['args'].pass_argument('args', 'sync2')

def execute(node):
    for value in node.func_arguments.values():
        if value:
            print(value)
            return execute(value)
        else:
            print(node.user_parameters)

execute(node)
```

I can execute functions if there aren't any missing arguments, but I can't find a way to implement a function that can receive any arguments from the user. How should I handle cases where user-specified arguments are required, but they haven't provided them yet?